# Logstash docker container filling up the root disk space in overley2 folder

Tags: linux, docker, logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

I am just posting this question and answering because I couldn't find any help anywhere. I had to troubleshoot myself and found the solution that's why I thought to share my findings here which might help others stuck in similar problem.

**Problem:**
I had weird issue while running my `ELK (Elasticserch, Logstash, Kibana) stack` using docker containers. This ELK stack was working fine with one or two log sending agents. But when I put load on ELK stack and pointed almost 10-12 log agents which sent almost 17 million logs to server and then I find that the root disk is 100% consumed although I had already mapped the volumes for `logstash` in docker-compose file as below.

```
volumes:
  - /example/app-elk/logstash/config:/etc/logstash/conf.d:ro
  - /example/app-elk/logstash/logstash.yml:/etc/logstash/logstash.yml:rw
  - /example/app-elk/logstash/pipeline:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline
```

Due to this Logstash was in not responding state and I was getting error in log sending agents `TCP Connection Timeout`

I used `filebeat` as log sending agent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my investigation I find that there is folder in `logstash` container `/usr/share/logstash/core` having the biggest size and causing the disk filling.

I mapped this volume as well in my volume mappings for `logstash`. The configuration looks like below code snippet.

```
volumes:
  - /example/app-elk/logstash/config:/etc/logstash/conf.d:ro
  - /example/app-elk/logstash/logstash.yml:/etc/logstash/logstash.yml:rw
  - /example/app-elk/logstash/pipeline:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline
  - /example/app-elk/logstash/core:/usr/share/logstash/core
```

After applying this change my root disk is just 17-20% used.